# Who was praised: « toutes les louanges qu'ils m’ont faites »?

Tags: sens

> toutes les louanges qu'ils **m**’ont faites à **son** sujet

Here, the phrase « à son sujet » makes it clear that they told **me** how highly they think of her, praising **her** to the skies. But what about if you drop the part « à son sujet »?

> toutes les louanges qu'ils **m**’ont faites

I wonder if it seems like all the praise was directed towards **me**, or is it left unclear who was praised?

Do you always need to have the noun « louanges » accompanied by « au sujet de qn » or « sur qn »?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Toutes les louanges qu'ils **m**'ont faites* can be used without specifying the recipient and in such case, it more than likely means the praise was directed to the speaker.

Note that ***louanges*** being a little formal, you'd probably hear more often *tous les **compliments** qu'ils m'ont faits*.